# try catch error in javascript - get more error details

Tags: javascript

How can I get more error details from a javascript catch?

Are there more parameters to get more details from the caught error.

```
try { 
    var s = null;
    var t = s.toString();
  } catch(err) {
    alert(err);
  }
```

Comment: Try firefox with firebug plugin or using chrome. Press F12 and check out the console. Instead of alert you can console.log(err) In the console you can see the error details (click on it). Any object that you console.log can be clicked on.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [Error Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) has several properties that you can use. One property you can use to get the message of the error, is `.message`, as in:

```
catch(err) {
    alert(err.message);
  }
```

The `.name` property returns the type of error as in:

```
catch(err) {
    x = err.name;
    //  ... do something based on value of x
  }
```

The name describes the type of error, and the value of `.name` can be : `EvalError, RangeError, ReferenceError,  SyntaxError, TypeError` , and  `URIError`. You may decide to handle the error differently depending on the error type which is returned by the `.name` property.

A good tutorial can be found on [JavaScriptKit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/trycatch2.shtml). The is also an article on the error object at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error).

Answer (score 6):

Check this link out:
[Reference to Error.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/prototype)

Basically you have `err.name` and `err.message`.

You also have a few vendor-specific extensions:

Microsoft => `err.description` and `err.number`.

Mozilla => `err.fileName`, `err.lineNumber` and `err.stack`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function message()
{
  try
  {
  }
  catch(err)
  {
   alert(err.message); 
 }
}
```

[**SEE HERE**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)  and [**HERE**](http://rakeshdiscovery.blogspot.in/2008/12/exception-details-in-javascript.html)